# Use prefetch related many to many table without many to many field

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.8. I have three tables.

```
A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

AB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

Is it possible to get all A's with their corresponding rows from AB using prefetch related? May be something like this:

```
A.objects.filter(name='abc').prefetch_related('AB')
```

Comment: Can you flip your query? `AB.objects.filter(a__name='abc')...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should user the related name instead of the class name itself. something like this will do the job:

```
A.objects.filter(name='abc').prefetch_related('ab_set')
```

Comment: AttributeError: Cannot find 'ab_set' on Booking object, 'ab_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: did you replaced `ab_set` with your actual model name?

Comment: I replaced ab with my model name - all small letters.

Comment: didn't you change your field related_name?

Comment: Yes. I found my mistake. I was using wrong model name. Instead of `ab` I added `abs` :)

Comment: I am getting the same error when I am using other table. Is it because I am using the `related_name` while defining foreign key.

Comment: Also, is it possible to see the prefetch related query. I guess prefetch related will get only records for which A exist.