# Django prefetch_related on ManyToMany(through)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to minimize my number of queries on a `ManyToMany(through=)`, but I seem to be causing an n+1 simply by prefetching.

Models:

```py
class Member(ImmutableModel):
  organizations = models.ManyToManyField('Organizations', through='MemberOrg', related_name='members')

class MemberOrg(ImmutableModel):
  member = models.ForeignKey('Member', related_name='member_orgs')
  org = models.ForeignKey('Organization', related_name='member_orgs')

class Organization(ImmutableModel):
```

From a clean database, if I setup these models:

```py
member = Member.objects.create()
org = Organization.objects.create()
MemberOrg.objects.create(member=member, org=org)
MemberOrg.objects.create(member=member, org=org)
```

Then fetch:

```py
Member.objects.all().prefetch_related('member_orgs')
```

I get the following queries:

```
(0.009) SELECT "main_member"."id", (...) FROM "main_member"; args=()
(0.010) SELECT "main_memberorg"."id", (...) FROM "main_memberorg" WHERE "main_memberorg"."member_id" IN (1); args=(1,)
(0.005) SELECT "main_member"."id", (...) FROM "main_member" WHERE "main_member"."id" = 1; args=(1,)
(0.003) SELECT "main_member"."id", (...) FROM "main_member" WHERE "main_member"."id" = 1; args=(1,)
```

---

I am trying to figure out why I am getting one query of the `Member` model per `MemberOrg`. This behavior continues as I add `MemberOrg`-s. I can't find any mention of this in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607984) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32781561) suggest this is how they solved the problem, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended for me.

(Note: This is just an example schema - my requirements are more complex and I am tied to this model setup.)

Django: 1.9.1
postgres: 9.6